# spyOn not working with js methods inside iron router action (Server Integration)

Tags: testing, meteor, jasmine, velocity, iron-router

I'm trying to write test for a twilio application. My strategy is to make a http request to my server, like what twilio will do when receiving a phone call on one of my numbers, then analyze the xml retrieved from the server response.

I tried to stub Meteor.users.find. But, I didn't succeed. The call to Meteor.users.find is from a route action. I thought maybe there is a problem with spyOn and functions inside routes actions.

So, to investigate more in the problem. I decided to make the problem simpler. Here is the code:
in `/server/routes.js`

```
ExpertTest = {
    foo: function () {
        console.log("called");
        return 4;
    }
};


allo = function () {
    var res = ExpertTest.foo();
    console.log(res);

};

Router.route('/call-api/intro', {
    where: "server",
    name: "Intro",
    action: function () {        
        ExpertTest.foo();

        this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'});
        this.response.end();
    }
});
```

and in `tests/jasmine/server/integration/IVRSpec.js`

```
describe("With our IVR", function () {

    it("green test", function () {
        spyOn(ExpertTest, "foo").and.returnValue(50);

        allo();

        expect(ExpertTest.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });




    it('red test', function() {
        spyOn(ExpertTest, "foo").and.returnValue(50);

        var callFirstResult = HTTP.get(baseUrl + '/call-api/intro');

        expect(ExpertTest.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

and here is the **error** in console:

```
jasmine-server-integration: 1 tests failed
With our IVR red test
Expected spy foo to have been called.
meteor://app/tests/jasmine/server/integration/IVRSpec.js:81:32: Expected spy foo to have been called.
```

I created a C9 workspace. You can inspect it [here](https://ide.c9.io/ziedmahdi/jasmine-problem).

I have also created a [git repo](https://github.com/ziedmahdi/jasmine-problem) to reproduce the problem.

Did I do something wrong?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, @sanjo gave me the right solution. The problem was with the `baseUrl` var. In fact, the `baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000"` need to point to mirror url. So the solution is to use:

`var callFirstResult = HTTP.get(Meteor.absoluteUrl('firstRoute'));`

or

`var callFirstResult = HTTP.get(process.env.ROOT_URL + 'secondRoute');`